# Difference between iterable.forEach() and iterable.stream().forEach()

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

It looks like I can call `list.forEach(a -> a.stuff())` directly on my collection, instead of `list.stream().forEach(a -> a.stuff())`. When would I use one over the other (`parallelStream()` aside..)?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are a few differences:

`Iterable.forEach` guarantees processing in iteration order, if it's defined for the Iterable. (Iteration order is generally well-defined for Lists.) `Stream.forEach` does not; one must use `Stream.forEachOrdered` instead.

`Iterable.forEach` may permit side effects on the underlying data structure. Although many collections' iterators will throw `ConcurrentModificationException` if the collection is modified during iteration, some collections' iterators explicitly permit it. See `CopyOnWriteArrayList`, for example. By contrast, stream operations in general must not interfere with the stream source.

If the Iterable is a synchronized wrapper collection, for example, from `Collections.synchronizedList()`, a call to `forEach` on it will hold its lock during the entire iteration. This will prevent other threads from modifying the collection during the iteration, ensuring that the iteration sees a consistent view of the collection, and preventing `ConcurrentModificationException`. (This will also prevent other threads from reading the collection during the iteration.) This is not the case for streams. There is nothing to prevent the collection from being modified during the stream operation, and if modification does occur, the result is undefined.

Comment: "preventing other threads from modifying it" — or reading from it either, surely? And your last point seems to imply that `Stream.forEach` contrasts with `Iterable.forEach` in allowing modification of the stream source. I doubt whether you meant to imply this!

Comment: I certainly didn't mean to imply that! I guess I should clarify that last bit.